# Cutting mp4 h264 video file without reencoding

Tags: c#, video, h.264, mp4

I am searching for a way to split or cut a mp4 video file encoded with h264, without reencoding. So far for editing a mp4 h264 encoded file I used Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 Pro. The problem is, that I always have to reencode the file and this takes time, unnecessary time if I only want to cut or split the video file. Any help or pointing into the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: depends on how the video was encoded. unless you split on a key frame boundary, usually re-encoding at least part of it is required.

Comment: split on a key frame boundary would be fine for me, but I did not find any library I could use for this "easy" task in c#

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how to split video without re-encoding (transcoding) but on Windows 8 transcoding a video has been built-in:

> To trim the file, call the aysnc method PrepareFileTranscodeAsync and then call the TranscodeAsync method on the PrepareTranscodeResult object.

For example:

```
async void TrimFile(StorageFile srcFile, StorageFile destFile)
{
    MediaEncodingProfile profile =
        MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);

    MediaTranscoder transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();

    // Set the start of the trim.
    transcoder.TrimStartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

    // Set the end of the trim.
    transcoder.TrimStopTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 9);

    PrepareTranscodeResult prepareOp = await
        transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(srcFile, destFile, profile);

    if (prepareOp.CanTranscode)
    {
        var transcodeOp = prepareOp.TranscodeAsync();
        transcodeOp.Progress +=
            new AsyncActionProgressHandler<double>(TranscodeProgress);
        transcodeOp.Completed +=
            new AsyncActionWithProgressCompletedHandler<double>(TranscodeComplete);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (prepareOp.FailureReason)
        {
            case TranscodeFailureReason.CodecNotFound:
                OutputText("Codec not found.");
                break;
            case TranscodeFailureReason.InvalidProfile:
                OutputText("Invalid profile.");
                break;
            default:
                OutputText("Unknown failure.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[How to trim a video file (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868176.aspx)

It is also possible to [Splicer](https://splicer.codeplex.com/) (uses [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)) for older Windows.

Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint. The project is shifted, but as soon as I have to deal with this problem again, I will take a look on your solution/example.

Answer (score 0):

[libmp4v2](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/) gives you the primitives to build something to do this yourself. Im not aware of a free off the shelf solution that does just this, though it would be relatively easy to implement as long as you are cutting on I frame boundaries.

Comment: @Kevkong I don't believe it exists.  You are most likely have to p/invoke to something to do much if any low level manipulation of media from c#.

Comment: If one wants to make brutal arbitrary cuts on an MP4 file and just consequently modify the header, I really hope he'll not need super optimized low-level C code. What I'd do is checking the format specs then make some test to see how decoder digests the broken sequences. On new platforms like WP and WinRT, less is better.